# Javafx can't load new added image

Tags: java, image, javafx

This is my code:

Controller.java

```
package sample

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;


public class Controller {
    @FXML
    Button button;
    @FXML
    TextField text;

    @FXML
    ImageView iv;

    public void handleBtn()
    {
        String name = text.getText();
        String address = "./res/"+name+".png";
        Image image = new Image(address);
        iv.setImage(image);
    }

}
```

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="387.0" prefWidth="481.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="text" layoutX="41.0" layoutY="64.0" />
      <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="64.0" layoutY="169.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtn" text="Button" />
      <ImageView fx:id="iv" fitHeight="261.0" fitWidth="209.0" layoutX="222.0" layoutY="56.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and the file structure:
[image]

When I run my project and type 1 in text field and click the button, it shows the picture. Now without closing the program, I add a 2.png file to the res folder. And type 2 in text field. after clicking the button, It gives me "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found" and can't load the image. But if I terminate the program and rerun it, typing 2 and clicking button works fine.

Comment: You will need to show your code in order for us to be able to help you here. Please see how to create a [mcve] and then [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: @Zephyr I completely changed the question so it now reflects my problem in a general way.

Comment: It is still likely a problem with your code, which we need to see in order to reproduce the problem. What you're currently describing should not be possible.

Comment: @Zephyr I try to write a completely independent code now and I will add that here soon.

Comment: Shouldn't your url, actually be a url?

Comment: @Zephyr I added complete code.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FxTemp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Image image = new Image("file:///home/username/Desktop/test.png");
        primaryStage.setTitle("animated");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        imageView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, evt->{
            System.out.println("click");
            Image imager = new Image("file:///home/username/Desktop/test.png");
            imageView.setImage(imager);
        });
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(imageView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 512, 512));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

If I change the test.png and click on the view, I see the new image.

You're not really supposed to be added files to your 'resources', those are files you provide before execution. Intellij will copy the files to a location and use that location on your class path. Then you can access them via `getResource`.

If you're going to have a folder that you add files to, then you want to access those files, you can do something like.

```
String nextImage = new File("./res/image.png").toURI().toString();
```

Then you should be able to load your new image provided your path is correct.

Comment: I completely Changed the question body to clearly reflect my problem and added some code.

Comment: @amirna `String address = "./res/"+name+".png";` is not a URL, exactly as your exception is claiming. See how I formed a url, if it is a file, `file://` then the path.

Comment: why it works at first then? because if I don't add anything, It works fine!. Anyway, If I really need to add complete absolute path, How to convert this relative address to url? because actually it must work on a lot of systems and not just my system.

Comment: @amirna It doesn't run in the source directory. When you compile and run in intellij, it copies resources over. If you check in your out folder it probably copies the resources over.

Comment: So how to make it load files that are added when the program is running? the files are added in res folder by user. So i need to convert relative path to full path.

Comment: @amirna if it is a file path, then use a file url, eg "file://relative/path.png" or "file:///absolute/path/relative/path.png"

Comment: can you say what I actually need to type in my example? I added project folder structure in question body.

Comment: @amirna I have updated the  post. Essentially, you do not want to be adding files to your resources. Make the ./res/image.png a file url and load the image. I added some description to my example.